# Bumping a question

Tags: discussion, questions

Recently I asked a question and was alerted to a question that I was duplicating (and I do appreciate the info). I found, though, that in the original question, a major component was not answered -- so I am still left with at least part of my question. Is there a way to "reintroduce" a question, or bump it back to the top of the list so that it might get new eyes and reevaluation without running afoul of a simple duplication?

I know that when I load Mi Yodeya up, I stick with the most recent questions and rarely search through old ones. Having a question back on the first page would increase the odds that someone might have something new and different to say about it but a dupe is still a dupe.

Ty,
d

Answer (score 4):

You can try offering a [bounty](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties).

From the [FAQ](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty):

> What if I don’t get a good answer?
>
> First, make sure you’ve asked a good question. To get better answers, you may need to put additional effort into your question. Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will naturally bump your question and get more people interested in it.
>
> If, despite your best efforts, you feel questions aren’t getting good answers, you can help by offering a bounty.
>
> Slice off anywhere from +50 to +500 of your own hard-earned reputation and attach it to any question as a bounty.
>
> The bountied question will appear with a special indicator in all question lists, and it will also be visible on the home page Featured tab for 7 days.

Comment: my question isn't so much about the bounty system (which I, personally do not like as I believe it appeals to the mercenary sense and not to a more intellectual one) but about the reintroduction of a question to the top of a queue without duplicating it.

Comment: @Dan When you start a bounty, it automatically gets bumped to the top of the home page, in addition to being in the featured tab. So setting even the smallest bounty size would give the question many views over the week.

Comment: I don understand that but even ignoring my own distaste for bounties, I was just wondering if there was a way to drop a link at the top of a queue to an old question that might have new relevance so that I don't repost the same thing. Questions which don't get answered by the time they move off of the first page get lost (especially if they have 1 unsatisfying answer, as they are less likely to get picked up in the "unanswered" category).

Comment: another problem I would have is that half the original question was answered. My "bounty" would only be on a part of the question. Bumping with a "n.b." would be preferred.

Comment: @Dan What do you mean by "n.b."? "New bounty"? An English version of "[נ"ב](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A0%22%D7%91)"?

Comment: @ba nota bene http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nota+bene

Comment: @Dan So it really *is* a נ"ב (according to its Wikipedia page). I didn't know it was actually used in English.

Answer (score 2):

Editing a question (or answer) is also a way to get questions bumped to the top.

As [Jeff Atwood once said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8317/161519):

> we encourage people to revisit and edit their old posts to include better and more up-to-date info

Comment: but the original wasn't my question.

Comment: @Dan You can edit others' posts if you improve them in some way. [FAQ#editing] and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit

Comment: I did think about that, BTU the improvement I have in mind is to remove a part of the question and leave that which has yet to be answered -- that seems a bit extreme.